# rostest does not show log message

Tags: ros, rostest, rosconsole

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have an annoying problem of dispalying the ros log message during testing.
I have some functions showing ROS_ERROR when errors occur and a test program to test these error cases.

If I run a pure gtest program, all ros log messages show up normally in console.

As long as I need to run a test node with `rostest`, all ros log messages disappear from console. From `rostest` documentation about the `test` tag: no `output` attribute as tests use their own output logging mechanism.

`rostest --text` also does not help. But if I put `std::cout` in the test program, `rostest` will dispaly these messages.

Thanks for any suggestions.

kai

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267191/rostest-does-not-show-log-message/) by [khu](https://answers.ros.org/users/31323/khu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-07-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have had this issue with setting up GTests in ROS before.

You need to properly initialize the logger and set the logger level in ROS

To initialise the logger either

```
ros::init(argc, argv, "node_name");
```

or

```
ROSCONSOLE_AUTOINIT;
```

To set the logger level either

```
ros::start();
```

or

```
if(ros::console::set_logger_level(ROSCONSOLE_DEFAULT_NAME, ros::console::levels::Debug))
{
    ros::console::notifyLoggerLevelsChanged();
}
```

Of course you can just use rosconsole directly

```
#include <ros/console.h>
#include <log4cxx/logger.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ROSCONSOLE_AUTOINIT;
    log4cxx::LoggerPtr my_logger = log4cxx::Logger::getLogger(ROSCONSOLE_DEFAULT_NAME);
    my_logger->setLevel(ros::console::g_level_lookup[ros::console::levels::Debug]);
    ROS_INFO("test logger);
    exit 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [phillip](https://answers.ros.org/users/34530/phillip/) with karma: 36 on 2018-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2